# PHP Find and delete specific line set in large text file

Tags: php, text

I am trying to remove certain line set based on ipaddress in large text file having approx. 60,000 lines. Each line set starting from MaxBytes[ipaddress] and ending with `</TABLE>` and a blank line present between each line set. There is variation in table lines in text file.

Sample line set :

```
MaxBytes[192.168.1.1]: 10000  <--start line
 <TABLE>
   <TR><TD>IP Address:</TD><TD>192.168.1.1</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Max Speed:</TD> <TD>300</TD></TR>
 </TABLE> <-- end line (Need to delete lines from start to end line)
```

I am trying to find start line using below codes (supported by Yerke) but unable to find out way to find next line number containing `</table>` tag. I need to find out start and end line number of line set containing specific ipaddress and delete it.

I am a beginner in coding, so I might need extended guidance.

codes :

```
<?php
$dir = "example.txt";
$searchstrt = "192.168.1.1";

///// find details
function find_line_number_by_string($dir, $searchstrt, $case_sensitive=false ) {
    $line_number = [];
    if ($file_handler = fopen($dir, "r")) {
        $i = 0;
        while ($line = fgets($file_handler)) {
            $i++;
            //case sensitive is false by default
            if($case_sensitive == false) {
                $searchstrt = strtolower($searchstrt);
                $line = strtolower($line);
            }
            //find the string and store it in an array
            if(strpos($line, $searchstrt) !== false){
                $line_number[] =  $i;
            }
        }
        fclose($file_handler);
    }else{
        return "File not exists, Please check the file path or dir";
    }

    return $line_number;
}

$line_number = find_line_number_by_string($dir, $searchstrt);
var_dump($line_number);
?>
```

Sample example.txt

```
MaxBytes[192.168.1.1]: 10000
 <TABLE>
   <TR><TD>IP Address:</TD><TD>192.168.1.1</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Max Speed:</TD> <TD>300</TD></TR>
 </TABLE>

MaxBytes[192.168.1.2]: 30000
 <TABLE>
   <TR><TD>IP Address:</TD><TD>192.168.1.1</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Max Speed:</TD> <TD>300</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Name:</TD> <TD>ABC</TD></TR>
 </TABLE>

MaxBytes[192.168.1.3]: 10000
 <TABLE>
   <TR><TD>IP Address:</TD><TD>192.168.1.1</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Max Speed:</TD> <TD>200</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Location:</TD> <TD>INDIA</TD></TR>
 </TABLE>
```

I found some workaround to get line numbers of line set containing desired ip address. Does anyone suggest better way to do it.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

$dir = "example.txt";
$searchstrt = "192.168.1.2";
$searchend = "</TABLE>";

///// find details
function find_line_number_by_string($dir, $searchstrt, $case_sensitive=false ) {
    $line_number = [];

    if ($file_handler = fopen($dir, "r")) {
        $i = 0;
        while ($line = fgets($file_handler)) {
            $i++;
            //case sensitive is false by default
            if($case_sensitive == false) {
                $searchstrt = strtolower($searchstrt);
                $line = strtolower($line);
            }
            //find the string and store it in an array
            if(strpos($line, $searchstrt) !== false){
                $line_number[] =  $i;
            }
        }
        fclose($file_handler);
    }else{
        return "File not exists, Please check the file path or dir";
    }

    return $line_number;
}

$line_number = find_line_number_by_string($dir, $searchstrt);
//var_dump($line_number);
$start = $line_number[0];

////////////////////////

function find_line_number_by_string1($dir, $searchend, $case_sensitive=false, $start)  {
    $line_number1 = [];
    if ($file_handler1 = fopen($dir, "r")) {
        $i = $start;
//      $i = 0;
        while ($line1 = fgets($file_handler1)) {
            $i++;
            //case sensitive is false by default
            if($case_sensitive == false) {
                $searchend = strtolower($searchend);
                $line1 = strtolower($line1);
            }
            //find the string and store it in an array
            if(strpos($line1, $searchend) !== false){
                $line_number1[] =  $i;
            }
        }

        fclose($file_handler1);
    }else{
        return "File not exists, Please check the file path or dir";
    }

    return $line_number1;
}

$line_number1 = find_line_number_by_string1($dir, $searchend, $case_sensitive=false, $start);
$first = $line_number[0];
$last = $line_number1[0];
//var_dump($line_number1);

for ($x = $first; $x <= $last; $x++) {
    echo "Line number to be delete : $x <br>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution of my question. I have just added few more line in my existing code. Now its working fine as required.

```
$lines = file($dir, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
for ($x = $first; $x <= $last; $x++) {
    echo "Line number to be delete : $x <br>";
    $lines[$x] = '';
     unset($lines[$x]);
}

//var_dump($lines);
file_put_contents($dir , implode("\n", $lines));
```